# How to Set the Correct Region/Market for Online Prints in Windows Live Photo Gallery?

Tags: windows-7, windows-photo-gallery

I'm based in The Netherlands. However, I prefer to use my PC with English Language software and operating system. I have the English (US) version of Windows 7 and Windows Live installed.

The consequence is that in Windows Live Photo Gallery, when I choose the "Order Prints" option, I get a list of US-based printing companies. How can I change the Region/Market setting so that I get printing companies offering services in The Netherlands?

My Windows LiveID account and profile are already set up to show that I'm based in The Netherlands, so the setting must be driven by something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here, since someone answered it for me on another forum today...

> The way to get a list from your region is to set your region in the Location tab in the windows Region and Language setting in Control Panel (and restart Windows for the new setting to take effect).